# Regarding usage of the word performance

Tags: grammar

I have to compare results for two models A and B across two case studies , C and D . In both the studies A performed better than B. But it performed much better in case study D. 
I have summarized it as :

On comparing the results for both the cases, it was observed that the difference in the overall model performance, between A and B, was more for case study D, as it was more complex.

Is it gramatticaly correct?
Should I write the following 
The difference in overall performances, between A and B, was more for case study D

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> The difference in overall performances between A and B was greater in case study D.

i.e. lose the commas, and use "greater" instead of "more".

Arguably, you should add, at the end of the sentence,

> than in the other case studies

but I don't think it makes it more readable.